# Why couldn't Nebula see Adam Warlock?

Tags: marvel, comics, the-infinity-gauntlet

This is a question about the original comic story of Infinity war. It's a question about events near the end, so I'll put the rest in spoiler tags.

> At the end, Nebula has the infinity gauntlet, and Dr. Strange teleports himself, Silver Surfer, Adam Warlock, and Thanos to face her. However, despite having the Godlike powers of the gauntlet, being able see the future and know the second they arrive, she is unable to sense Adam Warlock.  This allows him to enter the soul stone and eventually wrest the gauntlet away from her.

My question is, why?

> What kept Nebula from being able to see Adam Warlock even though she had the limitless power of the gauntlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of facts first, from *The Infinity Gauntlet* #6.

1. Thanos said to Nebula "You haven't the vision necessary to properly exploit the infinity gems!"
2. Strange and Surfer stated "He stands outside the realms of chaos and order."

It's kinda like not knowing ultraviolet light exists.  Children don't know it exists so they don't look for it.  Nebula is that child.

She doesn't know that Warlock exists outside these 2 realms so she doesn't look for him when he arrives. Warlock also doesn't let his presence be known.  Strange, Surfer and Thanos know that Adam is there because they know this "secret" and use their powers to perceive Warlock. Of course, this isn't explained in the comic, you have to infer it yourself.

If Nebula had prior knowledge that such beings existed, she could have easily "wished" the gauntlet to let her see any such beings.

Nebula also doesn't sense Warlock because she misunderstands the capabilities of the Infinity Guantlet.  At most, she thinks its like a wish granting magic lamp/weapon of unlimted power.  If she was less ignorant, she could have stopped time and played with the guantlet and see what it's capabilities were.

But she just wasn't that smart/intelligent/knowledgeable.